# how can I print out data saved in LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

This is a simple code to get person's info. For example, when I type in enter#runnan#male#23#Earth it would save the data in LinkedHashMap. Also when I type in search#runnan it would search the datas in LinkedHashMap and find name runnan then print the whole info. I somehow managed to the saving part but whenever I try to search, it only shows the file address of the data.

```
import java.util.*;
public class PersonManage {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Map<String, Person> ps = new LinkedHashMap<String, Person>();
        ps.put("Runnan", new Person("Runnan","Male", 23, "Earth"));

    while(true){
        System.out.println("Person Manager > ");
        String in = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] arr = in.split("#");
        if(arr[0].equals("enter")){
            String name = arr[1];
            String gender = arr[2];
            int age = Integer.parseInt(arr[3]);
            String address = arr[4];
            ps.put(arr[1], new Person(arr[1],arr[2],age,arr[4]));
            System.out.println(arr[1]+"Saved");
            continue;
        }
        else if(arr[0].equals("search")){
            System.out.println(ps.get(arr[1]).toString());
            continue;
        }
        else if(arr[0].equals("exit")){
            break;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("write in format of enter#name#gender#age#address");
            System.out.println("or search#searchingname");

        }

    }
}
```

This is the overriden class.

```
public class Person {

String name;
String gender;
int age;
String address;
public Person(String string, String string2, int i, String string3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.name = string;
    this.gender = string2;
    this.age = i;
    this.address=string3;
}
public String toString(){
    String t = name+gender+age+address;
    return t;
}
}
```

Any help would be grateful to me and will so much be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try iterating over it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code with these inputs:

```
enter#Jhon#Men#23#Moon
enter#Mongo#Men#101#Jupiter
enter#Paul#Men#23#Earth
```

Then, when I used search:

```
search#Paul
```

I got:

```
PaulMen23Earth
```

Maybe you can edit your `toString()` method:

```
public String toString(){
    String t = "name: " + name+ ",\n" + "gender: " +  gender+ ",\n" + 
               "age: " + age + ",\n" + "address: " + address;
    return t;
```

Besides you should add a control when a name is not present in your list:

```
else if(arr[0].equals("search")){
   if(ps.get(arr[1])!= null) {
       System.out.println(ps.get(arr[1]).toString());
       continue;
   }
   else {
        System.out.println("This name is not present. You can add it using \"enter\" command");
        }
```

Comment: It was just a rendering "problem". I'm glad if I helped.

Answer (score 1):

In order to print all values from map to the console you should write something like:

```
else if (arr[0].equals("listAll")) {
    for (Person person : ps.values()) {
        System.out.println( person );
    }
    continue;
}
```

Or more concise version with Java 8 `Stream API` features:

```
else if (arr[0].equals("listAll")) {
    map.values().forEach(System.out::println);
    continue;
}
```

Comment: thank you, not really what I meant but got the hints from it:)

Comment: glad to help, welcome to the Stackoverflow! IMHO hints are more useful than someone's complete solution :)